# Facebook Bot in closed beta

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, chatbot

I want to give a small group of people automatically access to my Facebook Chat Bot, because I want to launch a beta for this.

After adding them to app via API they get a notification, but can only access if they are a Facebook Developer. That is not want I expected.

Is there the possibility
- To access the bot directly without a page?
- To give user access to page?

Or do you know a good way to start a closed beta for this?

Answer (score 0):

In my bot setting page I added two of my facebook friends as "Testers" and they can interact with my bot, even if they are not developers. However, my bot is linked to a public page. I gave them an access to my bot with the m.me/ sharing link (I got it from messenger.com)

[image]